# How do I get sum of amount between different periods

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have this issue.

I have a table that has a job field, date field and a cost field. The date field holds dates that work was done on a particular job while the cost field holds the amount spent on that date (Work may be done on several days for a single job)

I want to create a select statement such that I get the sum of cost spent between 0-7days and 8-30days of opening a job in different columns.

I tried this:

```
select a.[Job No_], DATEDIFF(day, MIN(b.[Posting Date]), a.[Ending Date]) as [WIP Age],
       SUM(b.[Total Cost])[Total WIP cost]
  [0 - 7 days]=case
         when (DATEDIFF(day, MIN(b.[Posting Date]), a.[Ending Date]) between 1 and 7) then
            SUM(b.[Total Cost])
        else 0
    end,
    [8 - 30 days]=case
        when (DATEDIFF(day, MIN(b.[Posting Date]), a.[Ending Date]) between 8 and 30) then
            SUM(b.[Total Cost])
        else 0
    end,
    [> 30 days]=case
        when (DATEDIFF(day, MIN(b.[Posting Date]), a.[Ending Date]) > 30) then
            SUM(b.[Total Cost])
        else 0
    end
 from [Job]a 
 right join [Job Ledger Entry]b
 on b.[Job No_] = a.[No_] 
 group by a.[No_]
```

It displays a result similar to this:

```
Job No_  WIP Age    Total WIP cost    0 - 7 days   8 - 30 days   > 30 days
 0001      40           9526.18          0           0             9526.18
 0002      27           1178.49          0        1178.49            0
 0003      3            2838.94       2838.94        0               0
```

This is not what I want, I want all cost spent between 0 - 7 days, 8 - 30 days and >30 days respectively.

Comment: I'm frightened by the use of spaces & other characters in the column names! Does the `Job` table contain an entry for the daily cost of a job? So a single job cost is posted every day, and to get the entire job cost you need to sum across multiple days? Also, is the `Job Ledger Entry` table's `[Posting Date]` column just used to query based on a certain day?

Comment: Hi Brent, sorry abt the use of spaces. its just to make the info clearer. The `job` table contains details about each job, but the `Job Ledger Entry` contains transactions each job makes on differents days. For instance. Job 001 may have transactions on it for 10days and each day has a cost implication (the entries for the transactions on each are captured in the `job ledjer entry table` ). The idea is to know the total spent on job 001 between 1-7 days, between 8-30 days etc.

Comment: I am possibly starting to get the idea, but am still far from being certain. I'd really welcome a sample of source data corresponding to the output.

Comment: No problem. But how do I send the source data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might do a better job:

```
SELECT
  a.[Job No_],
  [WIP Age] = DATEDIFF(day, MIN(b.[Posting Date]), MAX(a.[Ending Date])),
  [Total WIP cost] = SUM(b.[Total Cost]),
  [0 - 7 days] = SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, b.[Posting Date], a.[Ending Date]) BETWEEN 1 AND 7)
    THEN SUM(b.[Total Cost])
  END),
  [8 - 30 days] = SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, b.[Posting Date], a.[Ending Date]) BETWEEN 8 AND 30)
    THEN b.[Total Cost]
  END),
  [> 30 days] = SUM(CASE
    WHEN (DATEDIFF(day, b.[Posting Date], a.[Ending Date]) > 30)
    THEN b.[Total Cost]
  END)
FROM [Job] a
  RIGHT JOIN [Job Ledger Entry] b ON b.[Job No_] = a.[No_]
GROUP BY a.[No_]
```

Explanation: I put all the CASE expressions inside the respective SUMs. I also applied MAX() to `a.[Ending Date]` in the first DATEDIFF, because using that column without aggregating seemed wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But now the columns return a null value. The idea is this: The job table contains details about each job, but the Job Ledger Entry contains transactions each job makes on differents days. For instance. Job 001 may have transactions on it for 10days and each day has a cost implication (the entries for the transactions on each are captured in the job ledjer entry table ). The idea is to know the total spent on job 001 between 1-7 days, between 8-30 days etc. The posting date column is the day the transaction was made.